# How to show this is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

suppose that $E \subset D \subset F$,Where $E,F$ are fiels,and the $D$ is a Domain,how to show $D$ is a field ?
I am trying to show $\forall d \in D$,$d^{-1}\in D$,but I have no idea how to show it

Comment: What is your definition of domain?

Comment: integral domain

Comment: $F$ must be finite field extension of $E$. Check your question?

Comment: Yes ,sorry for my mistake, $F$ is algebraic extension of $E$

Comment: By the way, the request of $D$ being a domain is redundant, because it follows automatically from it being a subring of a field.

Comment: @Bruce, please fix your question. Also make it clear that $F/E$ can be an infinite extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002147/show-that-if-f-subset-d-subset-e-then-d-is-a-field

Answer (score 7):

As stated, the claim is false:
$
\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q[x] \subset \mathbb Q(x)
$ is a counterexample.

The claim is true if $F/E$ is finite. In this case, $D$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $E$ and so the map $D \to D$ given by $x \mapsto ax$ for $a \in D$ is surjective because it is injective when $a\ne0$.

More generally, the claim is true if $F/E$ is algebraic but not necessarily finite. In this case, take $a \in D$. Then $E[a]$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $E$ and the argument above still works.

Comment: What is the difference between $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ and $\Bbb{Q}(x)$?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor, polynomials x rational functions.

Answer (score 3):

Counter-example: let $K$ be field, and consider:
$$K\subset K[X]\subset K(X).$$

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that $F$ is a finite extension of $E$.

Because $F$ is a finite extension of $E$ we know that $d$ is algebraic over $E$.

Let $degf_{E}^d(x)=n$. Then we have

$$E(d)=\{a_0+a_1d+a_2d^2+\cdots+a_{n_{-1}} d^{n-1}\mid a_i\in E, i=0,1,...,n-1\}$$
Since $D$ is an integral domain, $a_0+a_1d+a_2d^2+\cdots+a_{n_{-1}} d^{n-1}\in D$ and so $E(d)\subset D$. In particular  $d^{-1}\in E(d)$, so $d^{-1}\in D$